# I'm trying to stop my function from displaying elements after a certain score length is satisfied. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

This code *should* stop after the length of the array `scores` reaches the length of five. Or so I thought. It doesn't and I cant't figure out what to do.

I also altered the code so that `scores.length < rounds.length` but that didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## JS

```
var scores = [];
var rounds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var startTime, clickTime, resultTime;
var button = document.querySelector('.button');
var box = document.querySelector('.box');

function game() {
    
    
        if (scores.length < 5) {
                box.style.display = 'none';
                button.onclick  = function() {
                box.style.display = 'block';
                startTime = Date.now();
        }
    
                box.onclick = function() {
                clickTime = Date.now();
                resultTime = (clickTime - startTime) / 1000;
                box.style.display = 'none';
        
                scores.push(resultTime);

        }
    
                console.log(scores);
        }
    
        else {
            
            box.style.display = 'none';
            button.style.display = 'none';
            
        }
}



game();
```

## CSS

```
.box {
    
    width:150px; 
    height:150px; 
    background-color:red;
    
}

.wrapper {
    
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    justify-content: center !important; 
    flex-flow:column;
    
}

.button {
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

## HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="reaction.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="button"></div>
            <div class="box">
            <div class="text">
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         <script src="reaction-timer.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please alter your question so that it contains the minimum code needed to demonstrate your problem. This code in insufficient.

Comment: `game()` is seemingly only called once, therefore your if statement only happens once

Comment: @enhzflep it's been updated for you. It's really simple.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Would a for loop be useful in this instance? Chab below mentioned using a while loop. Being the beginner I am, what would be more useful? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies around your `if` statement, which is evaluated only once at the beginning of the code execution, in the beginning of the execution of `game()`.

You want this condition to be checked before it enters the displaying part, and each time it does so. And moreover you want it to happen several times, until the condition fails. So in this case, you would need a `while` here.

It would do something like this:

```
var scores = []
while (scores.length < 5) {
   // The actions you want to repeat 5 times here
      scores.push('pushSomething');
}
```

But it's not actually what you want, I think you want to check if the click on the button can trigger on new push into `scores`. So you need a check there, not at the beginning of game().

So by better splitting your code it will be easy:

```
var scores = []
var rounds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var startTime, clickTime, resultTime;
var button = document.querySelector('.button');
var box = document.querySelector('.box');

function handleBoxClicked () {
     if (scores.length >= 5) {
         box.onclick = null; // to disable trigger of this function
         return false 
     }

     clickTime = Date.now();
     resultTime = (clickTime - startTime) / 1000;
     box.style.display = 'none';

     console.log(scores);
     scores.push(resultTime);
}


function game() {
       box.style.display = 'none';
       button.onclick  = function() {
            box.style.display = 'block';
            startTime = Date.now();
       }
       box.onclick = handleBoxClicked;
}


game();
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about an approach like this. This is clever and eliminates room for confusion. So you've broken up the process of starting, and then storing. Thanks so much!

Comment: Happy to help! If it fits your needs do not hesitate to mark this as answer to close the post, good luck!